# Split values by colon and add to variables via foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

Trying a learning exercise to build a sort of online shop without payment functionality. The values are being populated via a post variable. and are joined together as such ProductID:OrderAmount

I'm trying to split the values by the colon and assign each value inside a foreach loop but it doesn't want to play ball.

My current code is:

```
$products = explode( ',', $products );

foreach ( $products as $product => $order ) {

    //var_dump($product);

    $product_id = explode( ':', $order );

    foreach ( $product_id as $key => $value ) {

        $ProductID = $value[0];
                    $OrderAmount = $value[1];

    }


}
```

Any help would be great!

Thanks

Comment: Populate your post vars differently.

Comment: This is what arrays were invented for

Comment: I'm already getting the value from an array - I just need to split the value inside the array "product id" and "order amount"

Comment: Paste the value `$products` has and specify what variables and values you want to have in the end

Comment: You're just overwriting the values of `$ProductID` and `$OrderAmount` over and over in the foreach loop.

Comment: Right now you are assigning to those two variables ($ProductID and $OrderAmount) with every loop. So it gets overwritten. Please, describe a little more of what you want to achieve here.

Comment: I'm trying to get a product id which I can query the database on to retrieve the product data and then the ordered amount so I can send that to the manager.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using comma separated values when you have arrays in PHP ?

Comment: I joined two values product and ordered item in a post variable.